# Next/previous page link style wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm creating this Wordpress-theme and everythings going smooth, except for one thing. I would like to style my next/previous page links so that the next page-link is on the right side, and the previous page-link is on the left side. This is the auto-generated links that wordpress adds to the bottom of the page whenever the number of posts reaches it's maximum. I use the `posts_nav_link()` function, and my html code looks like this:

`<p><?php posts_nav_link(' | ','<-- Previous page', 'Next page -->'); ?></p>`

Sure, I can add float to the style of the `<p>` tag, but then both of the links will float either right or left. I want them to be on both left and right, and I really don't want a previous link on the first page (there's of course no content previous to the first page) or a next link on the last page.

Is there an easy way to do this? I'm new to this, so bear with me

Comment: Use `next_posts_link` and `previous_posts_link` instead, then you can output them separately and style them individually.

Comment: OK, added this as an answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `next_posts_link` and `previous_posts_link` instead, then you can output them separately and style them individually.